# Is using setTimeout in order to make sure function is called after useEffect bad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So let's say I have this code:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState();
const [test2, setTest2] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setTest2(undefined);
}, [test]);

const calledFunction => () {
   setTest(whatever);
   setTest2(thisIsWhatIwant);
}

return (
    <>
    {test2}
    <button onClick={() => calledFunction}></button>
    </>
);
```

After all of this code, I will get undefined in test2 even if I want to have "thisIsWhatIwant". So there is a small hack to achieve this:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState();
const [test2, setTest2] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setTest2(undefined);
}, [test]);

const calledFunction = () => {
   setTest(whatever);
   setTimeout(() => setTest2(thisIsWhatIwant), 1);
}
```

This will work because `setTimeout` will push setTest2 to the end of the stack (after the `useEffect`).

Is this bad practice? If so, is there any way to achieve what I want in a cleaner way?

Thanks.

//edit: calledFunction is called on click, on another button

Comment: When is `calledFunction` called? We also don't know when is `test2` evaluated either.

Comment: You have mismatched parentheses in your code.

Comment: `thisIsWhatIwant` is not the value test2 gets every time? Only when calledFunction is called?

Comment: `const calledFunction() =>` should be either `const calledFunction =>` or `function()`.

Comment: You're not even calling calledFunction anywhere, can you show where you call this function?

Comment: Why do you need to reset the value of `test2` in an effect whenever `test` changes? This seems to me the sign of an anti pattern somewhere, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? Using `test` and `test2` doesn't help and it's making things kind of confusing. What is the purpose of setting test2 to undefined in the test useEffect, especially since you're attempting to reset it right afterwards.

Comment: The changing of a state is asynchronous, so if you use `setTimeout` to be sure certain code is called after the state has changed, you are essentially hacking around :). You can compare it to using `setTimeout` to wait for an image to be loaded. It works, but you can never be 100% sure.

Comment: @Kokodoko yes. That is my idea basically - but is it a problem or is it okay?

Comment: It is a problem because there is no guarantee the state has changed. Instead, you should use `useEffect` to listen for state changes. You already do that for `test` so why not for `test2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity of this question makes this hard to answer. I'll assume the following scenario:

> You want to reset `test2` if `test` is changed except in some special circumstance.

You could create a custom setter instead of using a `useEffect` callback.

```
const [test, _setTest] = useState();
const [test2, setTest2] = useState();

const setTest = useCallback((newTest) => {
  _setTest(newTest);
  setTest2(undefined);
}, []);

const calledFunction = () => {
  _setTest(whatever);
  setTest2(thisIsWhatIwant);
}

return (
  <>
    {test2}
    <button onClick={() => calledFunction}></button>
  </>
);
```

In the above code we've defined the setter `setTest` to update both `test` and reset `test2`. "normal" code will be calling the `setTest` function, which closely follows your previous behaviour.

However in your special circumstance you can use `_setTest` which only updates the `test` without resetting `test2`.

Note there are two important differences:

1. The custom setter is not called on component mount.
2. If the value passed to `setTest` has the same identity as the previous value, then the `useEffect` callback will not be called and `test2` is never reset. Whereas with this custom setter `test2` will be reset regardless.

These differences in behaviour might or might not be relevant depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this could be using a `ref` which tells you that you want to skip your code in this effect.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState();
const [test2, setTest2] = useState();
const skipSetter = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if(skipSetter.current){
  setTest2(undefined);
  }
  skipSetter.current = false;
}, [test]);

const calledFunction => () {
   skipSetter.current = true;
   setTest(whatever);
   setTest2(thisIsWhatIwant);
}
```

The primary difference between this and your current approach is that there won't be an extra rerender, which happens in your implementation because of a `setState` inside the `setTimeout` callback.

**Note:** You will have to be careful with the value of ref variable though and ensure you are setting it correctly where applicable.